# How can I view images sorted by width and height?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, photo-management

I have a bunch of different sized images in a folder. I would like to sort the images by width x height and then copy some to another folder using a file explorer. (In this case i want to move all my 1024x461 sized files.)

I can't find a way of doing this in any of the Linux file explorers.

Dolphin had an option to view this information, however nothing shows in the columns when I select that option.

I have installed Nautilus-columns using the helpful information here: [Quickest method to display image dimensions for files in Nautilus in List View?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44470/quickest-method-to-display-image-dimensions-for-files-in-nautilus-in-list-view)

However that too shows blank columns with no information.

I can see the width x height if I use `identify` or `exiv2` in the terminal, however I just can't get the info in a GUI file explorer.

I can also see the information if I right click and select **Properties**.

Is there a way to do this in any Linux file browser?